# How to login to another website from current website

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

There are 2 websites, Website A and B. The requirement goes like this:

- Website A has a login page.
- On successful login of Website A, the user should be redirected to Website B homepage.
- Note:

  - The user account/credentials for both websites are same.
- Although Website B has an login page, the successful login in Website A should bypass the login page of Website B and show its (Website B's) homepage.

So my question is whether the above scenario is practially possible in C#, ASP.Net?

If possible, then how can the above requirement work in following environments:
- Both websites are hosted in the same domain.
- Both websites are hosted in different domains.

Can you please suggest me the ways of designing and implementing the above requirement.

Thanks in advance!!!.

Comment: use SSO . and google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to implement SSO for a .NET application.

Check out the following tutorials online:

Basics of Single Sign on, July 2012

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429166/Basics-of-Single-Sign-on-SSO

GaryMcAllisterOnline: ASP.NET MVC 4, ADFS 2.0 and 3rd party STS integration (IdentityServer2), Jan 2013

http://garymcallisteronline.blogspot.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-adfs-20-and-3rd-party-sts.html

The first one uses ASP.NET Web Forms, while the second one uses ASP.NET MVC4.

If your requirements allow you to use a third-party solution, also consider OpenID. There's an open source library called DotNetOpenAuth.

For further information, read MSDN blog post Integrate OpenAuth/OpenID with your existing ASP.NET application using Universal Providers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your suggestion. Will surely check it out.

Comment: @prash7 we cant directly provide the code . you try this and if you have issue in the code then again follow up. and it is useful kindly accept it

Comment: I checked different concepts suggested by you. It was helpful conceptually. But my real problem is to integrate this single sign on with already functional site. Currently the webpage I have developed is able to validate the credentials of the functional site. But on validate success, I'm not able to view the homepage of the functional site. Please suggest in this regard.

Comment: hi @prash7 for that first you have tweak your application to use SSO for Application A and B then you can do what ever you are looking for

Comment: Hi @Backtrack, One clarification. What is the general tweaking that would be necessary at Website A configuration to autologin and re-direct to Website B's homepage?. Please do consider that I just know the credentials of Website B user login for which I'm trying to bypass and do an auto login. Awaiting your suggestion in this regard.

Comment: @prash7 okay . plz kindly refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx and see figure 1 you can able to get some idea and also refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic and even if you have any doubt kindly let me know .. im sure i will help you my level best